# How to match calls to particular methods in Wart Remover?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I am writing a Wart Remover plugin. I want to detect calls to certain methods that may return `null`, such as `System.getProperty`. However, all the ways I have tried to match them, have failed. Here is my latest attempt:

```
import org.brianmckenna.wartremover.{WartTraverser, WartUniverse}
import scala.language.{implicitConversions,reflectiveCalls}

object LegacyJavaAPIs extends WartTraverser {

  def apply(u: WartUniverse): u.Traverser = {
    import u.universe._

    @SuppressWarnings(Array("org.brianmckenna.wartremover.warts.AsInstanceOf",
      "com.example.wart.LegacyJavaAPIs"))
    val getProperty = reify(System.getProperty("x")).tree match {
      case Apply(a,b) => a.toString
    }

    new u.Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
        if(tree.toString == getProperty)
          u.error(tree.pos,
            """|Do not use System.getProperty - it may return null.
               |Use sys.props instead.""".stripMargin)
        else
          super.traverse(tree)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Most ways I have tried result in no error for the line that should have an error - although when I tried `.symbol` instead of `.toString`, top-level trees started matching everywhere. I'm guessing `.symbol` is `null` in these contexts...

I also tried using `showRaw` and copying and pasting the relevant constructors out of that, but that didn't work because it wasn't valid Scala code - `java.lang` appeared as an identifier in the output of `showRaw`, instead of wrapped in whatever constructor it is actually wrapped in.

Comment: Try using quasis, e.g. `tree match { case q"java.lang.System.getProperty($x)" => ... }`.

Comment: @JCracknell that didn't work, unfortunately - but I finally found a way that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to find a part of the scala reflection API that isn't broken:

```
object LegacyJavaAPIs extends WartTraverser {

  def apply(u: WartUniverse): u.Traverser = {
    import u.universe._

    @SuppressWarnings(Array("org.brianmckenna.wartremover.warts.AsInstanceOf"))
    val systemStatic = rootMirror.typeOf[System].companion

    val getProperty = systemStatic.decl(TermName("getProperty")).alternatives

    new u.Traverser {
      override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit =
        if(getProperty.contains(tree.symbol))
          u.error(tree.pos,
            """|Do not use System.getProperty - it may return null.
               |Use sys.props.get instead.""".stripMargin)
        else
          super.traverse(tree)
    }
  }
```

We need to call `companion` (even though `java.lang.System` doesn't have a companion object because it's Java) because scala-reflect doesn't recognise the concept of static methods, and regards them as methods on a companion object. We also need to call `alternatives` because `getProperty` is overloaded.

If the type of interest is `scala.Predef`, it's necessary to tweak this slightly:

```
val predef = rootMirror.typeOf[scala.Predef.type]
```